# efficient approach to obtaining access to audio input device for a web app)

Tags: audio, web-applications

sorry newbie programmer here. I'm sure it's been asked before, but i can't seem to find what i'm looking for.

Say I want to create a web application that can receive input from a sound device(microphone, guitar input, etc.) Say if you one was to make an online tuner that used your microphone. How can I get that input in a web app? Also anything else related to the topic that you can point out, any advice is welcome.

If anybody has done something along those lines, or knows of a direction to point me in, would be much appreciated.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access any hardware nor OS-level specific resources (including input from sound card) from browser, however you can use embedded content (Java applet or Flash) to use it. Flash is probably the easiest way - it supports multimedia well on all supported platforms, but mind that it requires expilict user permission to get data from audio input. Also note, that you will probably need additional processing on your server-side, to handle audio data.

Think if you really need to do it with a web browser. Sound capture is more like a task for a standalone, downloadable application.